# How can I simplify this simple formula?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

:)

If we have `x+(x*l)`, is it possible to simplify this, on having only one single x?

Comment: This is more a math question than a *Mathematica* question. Anyway: `x*1 + x*l`. You know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Simplify.

```
x+(x*l) // Simplify
```